# Spring loading beans which are based on application.properties from a sub-module

Tags: java, spring

I have two Spring modules, Parent module which has a child modules dependency. Both projects has their own Spring annotated beans and beans are created using `@Bean`.
Project child has `child.properties` in his ressources, this file is used to set properties to a Bean in the child project.
Project Parent has his own `parent.properties` which is used too to create beans in parent projects.

=> Each two projects has their `ServiceConfig` class annotated with `@Configuration` which i use:

**Parent:**

```
@Bean public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configuration(){
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer props=new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        props.setLocations(new Resource[]{new ClassPathResource("parent.properties")});
        return props;
    }
```

**Child:**

```
@Bean public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configuration(){
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer props=new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        props.setLocations(new Resource[]{new ClassPathResource("child.properties")});
        return props;
    }
```

Now my question is: I need to autowire a bean from child to parent project and when i run Parent project (which has child project as dependency in the `pom.xml`), The child bean autowired couldn't be constructed because the `child.properties` aren't loaded. And when i debuged i see that spring enter only in the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean from the parent but not the child.
And when i remove the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` from the parent, Spring loads the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` Bean from the child project.

I can resolve this issue by placing the `child.properties` file in the parent project but i don't like this solution, i would like to keep each configuration by project.

Comment: Try to rename the method 'configuration' in the child submodule, to 'childConfiguration' and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the same bean name for both PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer beans, the child bean is overridden by the parent one (if you'll look closely in the log, you'll see it stated there)
try giving them different names

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your Spring configuration of the corresponding application with the `@PropertySources` annotation. It lets you  specify an array of `@PropertySource` files.

e.g.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:parent.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:child.properties")})
public class MyApp() // Add annotations on YOUR configuration 
{
    ...
}
```

Spring will add the properties of the annotation(s) to your application. For more information take a look at [chapter 23](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) in the spring documentation.